# Storing data from a text file in an array of structures C++

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, fstream

I am attempting to read data from a text file into an array of structures. The first iteration of the for-loop reads and displays everything correctly until it reaches the Boolean value, and every iteration after that does not display as expected. Is the bool value at the end causing the entire rest of the file to be read incorrectly? Or perhaps an issue stemming from getline?

```
int main()
{
    groceryProduct inventoryDatabase[25];
    ifstream fin("inventory.txt");
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "File could not be located.";
    }
    string itemName;

    for (int index = 0; index < 25; index++)
    {
        getline(fin, inventoryDatabase[index].itemName, '\n');
        fin >> inventoryDatabase[index].itemNumber;
        fin >> inventoryDatabase[index].itemPrice;
        fin >> inventoryDatabase[index].membershipPrice;
        fin >> inventoryDatabase[index].payByWeight;

        cout << inventoryDatabase[index].itemName << endl;
        cout << inventoryDatabase[index].itemNumber << endl;
        cout << inventoryDatabase[index].itemPrice << endl;
        cout << inventoryDatabase[index].membershipPrice << endl;
        cout << inventoryDatabase[index].payByWeight << endl;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

The structure:

```
struct groceryProduct
{
    double itemPrice;
    double membershipPrice;
    double itemWeight;
    int itemQuantity;
    string itemNumber;
    string itemName;
    bool payByWeight;
};
```

The output:

```
Apple
P0000
0.85
0.8
204 (expected output of 'false' instead of 204)
```

Output for every iteration of loop after first iteration:

```
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
204
```

Thank you, and please let me know if you require any more information.

File:

```
Apple
P0000
.85
.80
false
Orange
P0001
.95
.85
false
Lemon
P0002
.65
.60
false
```

Comment: Can we see the file you're pulling from? (Also, if this is homework, you should probably check your book and/or talk to your professor. We'll only point you in the right direction, but the more experienced programmers around here will not give you code, so as to not interfere with your learning.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Including a [Minimum Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here would definitely help get your answer solved. At the minimum, since `inventoryDatabase` is involved, it would be nice to know how you define and initialize it.

Comment: I appreciate the responses and have made a few edits accordingly. This is for a school assignment, however there are no real requirements given other than what functionality the program must have. The only response I will get from my instructor is, "I'm not sure, I'll do some reading and see what I can find out.", though I will make certain to ask him about it tomorrow.

Comment: Well, at least you talked to him. That's all we ask. :) You'd be surprised how many students come on here and ask us to do their homework for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of things I see that may be causing your problem.

1) An array is not "magically filled" with data. You have an uninitialized array, meaning that the data inside of it does not yet exist. At all.

What you have to do to remedy this is to add a new *instance* of the struct to the array at the start of each loop iteration.

How'd I spot that? Good rule of thumb: **if it's weird, it's memory-related**. Make sure you've initialized everything.

2) I've seen weird things happen when you use `getline` and `<<` next to each other. Is there a particular reason you are using `getline` over `<<`?

(I would need to re-research how to work around that weirdness. I used to hit it a lot in my C++ class way back when.)

3) What 1201ProgramAlarm said is absolutely correct.

---

Side note: Do NOT get into the habit of throwing `double` around because "I want to be able to arbitrarily throw a large value in there." It's a bad habit that wastes space, as `double` is twice as large as `float`.

Learn the difference between `float` and `double` - you will almost never need `double` outside of scientific situations, because it is for numbers with a LOT of decimal places. (That's oversimplifying it.) If you're using `double` over `float` all the time, you're using twice the memory you need - 32 bits per variable extra, in fact. It adds up. (And people wonder why modern programs need 8GB of RAM to do the same thing as their 100MB-RAM-using predecessors...)

Prices always have two (rarely three) decimal places, so `float` should fit that perfectly in all cases. Same with weights.

Comment: Noted on the point about double vs. float. I'm using getline because some of the item names contain spaces. I added the change recommended by 1201ProgramAlarm, and initialized everything within the structure definition. I got the expected '0' for the bool value, and the program made it one step further before it was unable to continue making changes to the values in the structure. The bool value is initialized to false, all strings initialized to " ", and all numbers initialized to 0.

Apple
P0000
0.85
0.8
0

Orange
0
0
0


0
0
0


0
0
0

Comment: Hm...create a new question with that info, and link me to it here. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your stream that the bool values are text with

```
fin >> boolalpha >> inventoryDatabase[index].payByWeight
```

You're seeing garbage data after the first bool input because failbit gets set in the stream and no further inputs will work until it is reset.  This results in you array's data staying uninitialized.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that would do it. I knew I was forgetting something in my answer...+1!